# How come I can import a python library in the shell but not in PyDev?

Tags: pydev

I'm trying to use the mdb library. I installed it with apt-get (python-mdb), and I can use it fine in the shell. But I can't get my code to run with it inside PyDev. In both cases I'm using python2.6.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify mdb library in your Pydev Python Interpreters's PYTHONPATH.

Go to Windows -> Preference -> Pydev -> Interpreters - Python

Under the library tab, add your mdb library path.

Comment: If it installed to somewhere that is on your `PYTHONPATH` already, you can just go into the dialog Tao describes and click "Apply" without changing anything; PyDev will then rebuild its index and hopefully notice the new package.